# Does google test support c++11 at eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, c++11, gcc, googletest

I'm using `xubuntu 14.4`, `eclipse luna`, `google test1.7`.

When I'm using google test with `c++11`, it doesn't work.

Before when I've used `xubuntu 12.4`, it's worked.

`gcc` version is: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2.

Doesn't `google test` support `c++11`?

There is error message:

```
12:08:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project googletest ****
make all 
Building target: googletest
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -L/home/smkang/test/gtest-1.7.0 -o "googletest"  ./src/googletest.o   -lpthread -lgtest
/home/smkang/test/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest.a(gtest-all.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::~ThreadLocal()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED5Ev]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED5Ev]+0x2b): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/home/smkang/test/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest.a(gtest-all.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::~ThreadLocal()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED5Ev]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED5Ev]+0x2b): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/home/smkang/test/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest.a(gtest-all.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::GetOrCreateValue() const':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x7c): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/home/smkang/test/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest.a(gtest-all.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::CreateKey()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE9CreateKeyEv[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE9CreateKeyEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/home/smkang/test/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest.a(gtest-all.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::CreateKey()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE9CreateKeyEv[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE9CreateKeyEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/home/smkang/test/gtest-1.7.0/libgtest.a(gtest-all.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::GetOrCreateValue() const':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x7a): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [googletest] error 1

12:08:59 Build Finished (took 1s.246ms)
```

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(Ex,test)
{
    std::cout<<"hello googletest"<<std::endl;

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your build compile option command line?

Comment: Indented error message by 4 spaces and added `<!-- language: none -->` tag so it looks more attractive. Also removed extra indents from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, googletest does support C++11, though it's not super-clear what you mean by 'support'. You can definitely compile googletest with a compiler that implementes the C++11 standard, if that's what you mean.

Regarding the errors, it looks like you're missing pthread libraries when you link. I'm not sure how to do this in eclipse, but in general, you need to pass '-pthread' to GCC when you compile.